# How to find Chrome after installing

Tags: google-chrome, launcher

I've just tried to install Google Chrome two ways:

- by downloading the package from Google, and installing it through Software Center.
- by following [the steps in this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/203768/beginner-how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-14.04/).

I finished both procedures without apparent errors, but I cannot find chrome through the Launch menu (even after reboot) or in `/usr/share/applications`.

I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed alongside Windows 10 on an Asus Zenbook UX305UA

Answer (score 2):

Run `google-chrome-stable` from the terminal

Comment: says "command not found"

Comment: It means that it is not installed. Run `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: chrome can still be installed through different package manager

Answer (score 1):

type the command below to locate chrome in your PC

```
whereis google-chrome
```

and execute `/usr/bin/google-chrome` command to run chrome